# Using Spring Security to manage iOS Homescreen web app sessions to prevent reauthn

Tags: ios, spring-security, sencha-touch, mobile-website

I recently ran into an issue where I'm being reauthenticated every time I launch or bring my web app to the foreground when launching it from the homescreen on iOS (I added it to the homescreen from Safari originally).  This does not happen when I'm in Safari directly.

My research has shown that this can be overcome in php by creating/restarting the session and then adding a session cookie as follows:

```
// Start or resume session
session_start(); 

// Extend cookie life time by an amount of your liking
$cookieLifetime = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; // A year in seconds
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$cookieLifetime);
```

Rather than do this programatically, I was wondering if there is a way to do this through the XML configuration. Otherwise, how could I accomplish something similar with Spring Security?

Here is my security-ctx.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="http403EntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint">
    </bean>

    <sec:http auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint">
        <sec:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="siteminderFilter" />
    </sec:http>

    <bean id="siteminderFilter" class=
            "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="principalRequestHeader" value="x-paas-uid"/>
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="preauthAuthProvider"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService">
            <bean id="userDetailsServiceWrapper"
                  class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
                <property name="userDetailsService" ref="ldapUserDetailsService"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="preauthAuthProvider"/>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <!-- Example using LDAP, but will ultimately use database service -->
    <sec:ldap-server id="ldapServer" port="636" root="o=home"
                          url="ldaps://ldap.home.com"/>


    <sec:ldap-user-service id="ldapUserDetailsService" server-ref="ldapServer"
                           group-search-base="ou=groups,o=home"
                           role-prefix="ROLE_" group-role-attribute="cn"
                           user-search-base="ou=people,o=home" user-search-filter="uid={0}"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Spring Security does not manage session timeout value. So there is no way to do it in security xml out of the box. If you want to define this value system wide (for all sessions) then look into your servlet container / application server documentation. In a case of Tomcat you can add following snippet to the `web.xml` descriptor:

```
<web-app ....>

    .....
    <session-config>
        <!-- value is in minutes -->
        <!-- 60x24x365 -->
        <session-timeout>525600</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    ....
</web-app>
```

Comment: I gave this a go, but it didn't help. I still get authenticated even if I just refocus back to that app after logging in.

Comment: So may be the problem is on iOS side? For example session cookie was not send second time, so new session was started?